# Add action options to easy-button like in leaflet.draw toolbar delete button leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

How to add action buttons to the easy-button plugin as shown here?

[image: 1]

```
L.easyButton('glyphicon-refresh', function(){
},{position:'topright'}).addTo(map)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot be done.

The functionality you're pointing out is "multiple actions per button". That feature is present in Leaflet.draw's [implementation of a toolbar](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/develop/src/Toolbar.js).

That functionality is **not** present in Leaflet-easy-button.

For clarity: The screenshot in the question seems to use Leaflet.draw, *not* Leaflet-easy-button.

Comment: Yes, its Leaflet.draw. I want to add similar functionality on the top right refresh button

Comment: Can you provide an example with a button

Comment: See https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.toolbar/blob/master/examples/subtoolbar.html

Comment: Thanks. I have added the functionality for sub actions. But how to add functionality on the main button